# Where do I put custom syntax highlighter definitions for Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

I have created a custom syntax definition in the [new `.sublime-syntax` format](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html), but I can seem to get it to appear in my list of available syntaxes...

I have tried putting it in:

- `<Install Location>/Packages`
- `<Install Location>/Packages/User`
- `<Install Location/Data/Packages`
- `<Install Location/Data/Packages/User`
- `%APPDATA%/Packages`
- `%APPDATA%/Packages/User`

The documentation seems to be bit light on how this works, but I'm hoping that someone can enlighten me!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The proper location for user-defined syntaxes, plugins, build systems, etc. is `Packages/User`, where `Packages` is the folder opened by selecting **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`***. I'm not on Windows at the moment, but I believe this is `%APPDATA%/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User`. Once you place the file there, it will be available from the syntax menu under `User`.

Also, please recall that `.sublime-syntax` files are only supported in the [dev builds](http://sublimetext.com/3dev) currently, and you need to be a registered user to run them. They will not work with [Build 3083](http://sublimetext.com/3).

Comment: The actual problem that I had was that there were syntax errors in the file, which I eventually found by popping up the console with `CTRL` + `'`, but knowing the correct place to put the file in the first place was pivotal to finding this error, so thank you!